# Switch to next view with UIWebView

Tags: ios, authentication, sdk

When you use the Facebook App and go to the Terms and Conditions view, there is a WebView. When you choose an option in the WebView you'll go to a new view.

Now I wanna make a login system with PHP. When the user login is succeded he'll go to an webpage. How can I set for example: When the UIWebView is on www.myserver.com/ok that the new view in my app will show?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `UIWebView` with delegate and check :-

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   NSLog(@"Loading: %@", [request URL]); //if url matches www.myserver.com/ok open your view
   return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: where you are creating UIWebView, set its delegate to self and automatically this function will be called

Comment: But I want that my UIWebView goes to login.php. When the login is OK, the file will direct to ok.html. On that moment (ok.html) must the view be opened.

Comment: Yes on this delegate method you can do what you said

Comment: check if your webview has set delegate

Comment: Check this link http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4342006%2Fset-a-delegate-for-uiwebview&ei=l1H8UKnrNYrRrQeJwYHABA&usg=AFQjCNEZaNr6DAWao261_tLFCAIMgsJgCA&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bmk&cad=rja